# mysql need to find the future packages from my table

Tags: mysql

I need Mysql query for this:
I am having a table with start_date and End_date columns from this i need to find out whose having future packages.Future packages means before his package expiry date he renewed his package.For ex:

```
person_id    start_date      end_date
101765       28-04-2017      27-07-2017
101765       10-07-2017      26-10-2017
```

From the above example the same person renewed his package before his package end has reached.
So i need to display these kind of packages to display as future packages.

Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Join the table with itself, and compare one row's `start_date` with another row's `end_date`.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable AS t1
JOIN yourtable AS t2 
ON t1.person_id = t2.person_id AND t1.id != t2.id AND t1.start_date < t2.end_date
```

I'm assuming you also have a unique `id` field in the table, which I use to prevent comparing a row with itself.